# Help me to choose a software for drawing

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration, drawing

Which is the best software for drawing below picture?

[image]

Comment: Inkscape would do what you needed, it's also FOSS. www.inkscape.org

Comment: Yeah, I like inkscape too. It runs on all platforms too.

Comment: Just copying it on inkscape ;)

Comment: There's a lot more information you could add to this question. What is your desired end result? How will it be used? What have you tried? Why is it not working? This could be drawn in anything from MS-Paint to Maya. There's no way for us to know *why* you need it redrawn and *how* it'll be used. So, there's no way for anyone to *accurately* suggest anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using CorelDraw X7 which is the software I use, it allows you to easily create vectors and retrace bitmaps images to vectors, also using line strokes it's pretty easy. 
Inkscape It's a free software that it's used to edit SVG's so you can also try it.

Comment: This comment is quite sparse - could you explain more about them?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a breeze in Illustrator, especially with the stroke options that you can use to ad in the arrow heads. That is what I would use, although, you could probably get away with some way more basic software.

Answer (score -2):

You can try Adobe Illustrator!  Its amazing tools to draw sketch and illustrate.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Your answer doesn't add anything that wasn't said before. If you want to know more about the site, please see [the help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!